# How can I expand a short URL, so I can get the full expanded URL in a variable?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to expand a short URL and store the long URL in a variable without accessing that link with the browser. Any ideas how I can do that in kotlin?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "short URL" and "long URL"

Comment: My nodejs backend redirects the short URL to a long URL.

Answer (score 1):

1. If your nodejs backend redirects the short url to a long url, you can create an API endpoint to fetch the long URL from your backend.
2. General idea is to send an HTTP HEAD request to the server which in turn will return a 301 response (Moved Permanently) with the Location header which contains the URI

   HEAD /5b2su2 HTTP/1.1
   Host: tinyurl.com
   Accept: */*

RESPONSE:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://stackoverflow.com
Content-type: text/html
Date: Sat, 23 May 2009 18:58:24 GMT
Server: TinyURL/1.6
```

This is much faster than opening the actual URL and you don't really want to fetch the redirected URL. It also plays nice with the tinyurl service.

Look into any HTTP or curl APIs available.

3. If you are using a third-party service to convert long URLs to short URLs, that same service provider must have an API endpoint which converts your short URL to long URL.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).